# Matriz em Python utilizando matplotlib e mplot3d

Tags: python

Olá,

O código abaixo está com o seguinte erro:

```
ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (3,3) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

Alguém sabe uma solução?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import itertools
A = np.matrix([[100.0,100.0,100.0],[0.0,0.0 ,64.3],[0.0 ,0.0,57.1]])
b = np.matrix([[100.0], [100.0],[100]])  # we will use the convention that a vector is a column vector
c = 0.0

def f(x, A, b, c):
    return float(0.5 * x.T * A * x - b.T * x + c)
def bowl(A, b, c):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
    qf = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    size = 20
    x1 = list(np.linspace(-6, 6, size))
    x2 = list(np.linspace(-6, 6, size))
    x1, x2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
    zs = np.zeros((size, size))
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            x = np.matrix([[x1[i,j]], [x2[i,j]]])
            zs[i,j] = f(x, A, b, c)
    qf.plot_surface(x1, x2, zs, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0)
    fig.show()
    return x1, x2, zs
x1, x2, zs = bowl(A, b, c)

def contoursteps(x1, x2, zs, steps=None):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    cp = plt.contour(x1, x2, zs, 10)
    plt.clabel(cp, inline=1, fontsize=10)
    if steps is not None:
        steps = np.matrix(steps)
        plt.plot(steps[:,0], steps[:,1], '-o')
    fig.show()
contoursteps(x1, x2, zs)
x = np.matrix([[-2.0],[-2.0]])
steps = [(-2.0, -2.0)]
i = 0
imax = 10
eps = 0.01
r = b - A * x
delta = r.T * r
delta0 = delta
while i < imax and delta > eps**2 * delta0:
    alpha = float(delta / (r.T * (A * r)))
    x = x + alpha * r
    steps.append((x[0,0], x[1,0]))  # store steps for future drawing
    r = b - A * x
    delta = r.T * r
    i += 1
contoursteps(x1, x2, zs, steps)
x = np.matrix([[-2.0],[-2.0]])
steps = [(-2.0, -2.0)]
i = 0
imax = 10
eps = 0.01
print ('b:\n', b)
print ('A:\n', A)
print ('x:\n', x)
r = b - A * x
print ('r:\n', r)
contoursteps(x1, x2, zs, None)
plt.plot([0, r[0, 0] * 0.5], [0, r[1, 0] * 0.5], 'g')
plt.show()
print ('||r||^2 =', np.linalg.norm(r)**2)
delta = r.T * r
print ('r.T * r = ',  delta)
delta0 = delta

ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (3,3) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

Comment: Que linha gera o erro?

Answer (score 1):

Em 3 pontos, o script declara a matriz `x` com *shape* (2, 1), porém, utiliza essa matriz em operações de multiplicação com matrizes de *shape* diferente (incompatíveis, para a operação de multiplicação de matrizes).

Um exemplo de onde esse erro ocorre na função `f()`:

```
def f(x, A, b, c):
    return float(0.5 * x.T * A * x - b.T * x + c)
                           ^--aqui
```

Apenas a título de exemplo, se você alterar os 3 pontos do script e acrescentar mais um elemento à matriz `x`, o script irá funcionar:

```
...
x = np.matrix([ [x1[i,j]], [x2[i,j]], [0.0] ])
...
x = np.matrix([[-2.0],[-2.0], [0.0]])
...
x = np.matrix([[-2.0],[-2.0], [0.0]])
...
```

**Importante**: Coloquei o valor 0.0 **apenas para funcionar**, mas você precisa verificar na descrição do algoritmo, qual deve ser o valor correto para inicializar a matriz `x`.

---

O script com os `0.0s` acima produz as seguintes imagens:

[image: figure1]

---

[image: figure2]

---

[image: figure3]

---

[image: figure4]

<sub>testado com: Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)</sub>